# Should I make a session for just one variable in my webapp, or use a GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm working on a web-application. I'm getting data from the DB, doing some computations and drawing a graph. This app is based on MVC 4, is written in C#/Razor and uses jQuery plugins.

I'm wondering if it is worthwhile to use a session for only one variable. The app is open and the variable has nothing to do with login. It is just an ID, which is constant for this app and I need it constantly. Or should I better put it in query string?

Comment: it should definately be stored in session or cache, depending on the scope of your id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that ID is going to be same for all the user then its better if you use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx), but if you have a separate ID for each user then you can store it in Session, rather than using querystring. It may difficult to manage query string with your application evolving over time.

> I' wondering if it is worth to use session for only one variable.

You should worry about storing large dataset in a session, since sessions are maintained on the server, for a simple ID, session is probably the best storage mechanism (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to store the variable in session. The session architecture is there for you to use, and it is a robust architecture that will eliminate the need for you to manage querystrings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a Session for access to the client. You can store anything in a Session index and will do the job you need